# Can't create custom screen resolution, and terminals are inaccessible

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a second monitor plugged in by a DVI to VGA converter. My Nvidia card and Ubuntu detects the monitor no problem, but I can't choose the max resolution 1680 x 1050. I know that's a supported resolution, because it's the one I use in Windows 7.

I tried to use`xrandr` to create the custom resolution like so:

```
xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 "1680x1050_60.00"
```

But I get this error:

```
  X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

Searching for this particular problem isn't much help at all, but I was lead to try to edit my `xorg.conf` file. I did so by following [Enabling Resolutions in Ubuntu 12.04 & Lubuntu 12.04](http://sammart.in/2012/05/29/enabling-resolutions-in-ubuntu-12-04-lubuntu-12-04/).

I ended up with this 10-monitor file in my  `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory:

```
    Section "Monitor"
  Identifier "Monitor0"
  Modeline "1648x1080_60.00"  148.11  1648 1752 1928 2208  1080 1081 1084 1118  -HSync +Vsync
EndSection
Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "DVI-I-0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1648x1080_60.00" "1024x768"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But that didn't work. I tried adding the above code to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` - but that didn't help either. The only shown resolutions for my display are the ones I had previously, I can't select any new resolution.

Also: I can't see any terminals when both monitors are plugged in. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> only leads to a blinking cursor, no login prompt, and the same goes for all other terminals <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

Running the nouveau drivers help my problem somewhat (At least I can access terminals with them), but I still can't select proper resolutions. Other information here: Nvidia driver version is 346.

```
    dalsgaard@dalsgaard:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3280 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 connected 1360x768+1920+211 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0*    59.8  
   1152x864       60.0  
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     50.0     60.1     60.0     50.0  
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1366x768       59.8  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1280x800       59.8  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9     50.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        59.9  
   640x480        59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x32e)  146.2MHz
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
```

Comment: Current status: I have tried installing a different window manager, as well as a couple of different drivers. I am using a DVI to VGA adapter on my second screen, and I have a hunch that the issue is somehow related to that. So far, nothing works short of installing the Novou drivers; but they simply don't function properly for my needs, and are therefore not an option for me.

Answer (score 1):

So far, after many days, I've been succesful in getting the terminal to work again. If anyone else has that problem, it's related to GRUB's resolution. Try this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1024x768-32,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
```

Remove this line:

```
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=
```

Save and close, and then do this:

```
sudo update-grub && sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot. Should fix that particular problem. As for the terminals, I'm still having no luck as of this writing.